rclone 1.60.1 in Ubuntu 24.10 has problems connecting to Microsoft OneDrive
The recent version of rclone (1.60.1) in Ubuntu 24.10 has a problem uploading files to Microsoft OneDrive. Although the connection credentials are correct, we get error messages like:
2024/12/03 18:51:41 NOTICE: <filename>: Failed to cancel multipart upload: unauthenticated: Unauthenticated (upload failed due to: unauthenticated: Unauthenticated)
2024/12/03 18:51:41 ERROR : <filename>: Failed to copy: unauthenticated: Unauthenticated
2024/12/03 18:51:41 ERROR : Attempt 1/3 failed with 1 errors and: unauthenticated: Unauthenticated
2024/12/03 18:51:51 NOTICE: <filename>: Failed to cancel multipart upload: unauthenticated: Unauthenticated (upload failed due to: unauthenticated: Unauthenticated)
2024/12/03 18:51:51 ERROR : <filename>: Failed to copy: unauthenticated: Unauthenticated
2024/12/03 18:51:51 ERROR : Attempt 2/3 failed with 1 errors and: unauthenticated: Unauthenticated
2024/12/03 18:52:01 NOTICE: <filename>: Failed to cancel multipart upload: unauthenticated: Unauthenticated (upload failed due to: unauthenticated: Unauthenticated)
2024/12/03 18:52:01 ERROR : <filename>: Failed to copy: unauthenticated: Unauthenticated
2024/12/03 18:52:01 ERROR : Attempt 3/3 failed with 1 errors and: unauthenticated: Unauthenticated
2024/12/03 18:52:01 INFO  : 
Transferred:           30 MiB / 30 MiB, 100%, 1006.176 KiB/s, ETA 0s
Errors:                 1 (retrying may help)
Elapsed time:        32.2s

2024/12/03 18:52:01 Failed to copy: unauthenticated: Unauthenticated

Retrying does not help.

The temporary solution is to install the latest version from https://rclone.org/downloads/
Remove Ubuntu version and install /usr/bin/rclone manually:
$ sudo apt purge rclone
$ sudo -v ; curl https://rclone.org/install.sh | sudo bash
$ rclone --version
rclone v1.68.2
- os/version: ubuntu 24.10 (64 bit)
- os/kernel: 6.11.0-9-generic (x86_64)
- os/type: linux
- os/arch: amd64
- go/version: go1.23.3
- go/linking: static
- go/tags: none

For snap-lovers the other solution (which I do not recommend) is to install the snap version:
$ sudo snap install rclone

